# How to fetch more than 100 items limit with Apollo graphql and strapi?

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo, fetch-api, strapi

Strapi (my api) fixed a limit of 100 fetch items. My question is how to fetch more than the 100 limit items in strapi. I made my request with Apollo graphql.

[I started to use parameters in my graphql request. But it limited the number only on the limit of the api. So, I can fetch only 20 items for example, but not 110 items for example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2wqi.png)

I imagine it's possible to pass parameter in the api call, but I don't know how to.

[I stock my api url here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x80VR.png)

[Here I use Apollo to dispatch my api.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Q6w.png)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to include properly formatted code, vs images of code. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) enumerates many reasons why this is very important. Also, as written, it's difficult to get an idea of your full question, as it requires clicking through to an image of each part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `_limit` parameter to control the limit of items you want to fetch

```js
_limit=300 //limits to 300 results
_limit=-1 //gets all results
```

You can read more on  [strapi docs](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/content-api/parameters.html#limit)